# Inno Setup - Uninstallation of several applications

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Our software is delivered with several additional applications. These are installed with an Inno Setup routine.

At installation Inno Setup installs all programs one after another that are listed in `[Run]`-section. So far so good.

Problem begins at uninstallation. I can't control the moment when an uninstaller is started. All uninstallers are started one after one without waiting until the previous has finished. Even flags e.g. `waituntilterminated` don't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `waituntilterminated` works (I assume you use `[UninstallRun]`, right?)

The problem might be that the uninstallers spawn a separate process for the uninstallation and exit. Inno Setup cannot detect that.

To solve this you have to code some custom solution. But without knowing details about the specific uninstallers, we can hardly help you further.